# Excel - CountIfs (column A has target value, column B is blank)

Tags: excel

First post, sorry if it's not according to site preferences. I searched around and couldn't find a post that was exactly like this, but sorry if this is a repeat as well.

I have the following code:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"="&C3, B:B,"<>""")
```

For clarity, the code is supposed to identify instances where column A has a specific value (C3), and where column B is empty.

I'm familiar with Countifs, but it was the "if blank" portion that I've been really struggling with. On top of that, column B is populated with formulas, making this seemingly more challenging from my perspective as a couple methods I've tried only work if the cells are truly unpopulated. What I can say is that this formula is working with almost all of my examples, except 1, and I have no idea why this would be. For that matter I'm not entirely sure why this code works at all.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To count if blank: `"="`

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"="&C3, B:B,"=")
```

Or if this is easier to understand:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"="&C3, B:B,"=" & "")
```

Which is the same.

Comment: I've tried those formulas, and variations on them earlier, but it's not providing the values I know it should. I think part of it may be that it's not counting the formulas as blank, even though they're not providing a value?

Comment: Look at the formulas, are they returning `""` or `" "`

Comment: The formulas are returning "" with no space

Comment: Remarkable. After changing the returns to " " and updating the countif statement to account for the space, they appear to be registering now.
Any idea why they weren't registering when they didn't have the space? Seems very arbitrary and silly.

Answer (score 0):

`"="` in `COUNTIFS` does not match blanks that result from formulas. Dont ask me why!

As workaround, you can use the flexible and never vexing `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=C3)*(LEN(B:B)=0))
```

Comment: I will add this to my toolbelt. Thank you very much.